# leaflet user location variables

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i'm new to javascript and having an issue with leaflet, i have a map set up and i am trying to set it up so that when a user clicks a link, an onclick function places the users latitude, longitude and accuracy in the url so that on the following page i can incorporate the values into a form. i'm guessing the issue i am having is scope related.

here is parts of the code:

```
var location;

function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
    L.circle(e.latlng, radius, {fill : false}).addTo(map);

    circle.addTo(map);
    location = '&la=' + e.latitude + '&lo=' + e.longitude + '&ac=' + e.accuracy;
}
```

and the a tag:

```
<a href="#?f=1" onclick="location.href=this.href + location;return false;">Roof Access Point</a>
```

when you click the link the onclick functions as expected but it comes up with undefined for the 3 variables eg:

```
#?f=1&la=undefined&lo=undefined&ac=undefined
```

its very perplexing because on the first line of the onLocationFound function it uses e.accuracy to define another variable, and it is working as it shows the circle for the accuracy area on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out "circle" had not been defined as a variable as was making the function fail a few lines above my code. by defining it above the function where i am defining "location" allows the function to complete and sets the "location" variable as expected.

damn flu made that so hard to find, should have spotted it in the log strait away.